# How to Edit a Partition table in a linux iso image

Tags: linux, android, partition-table

***Note : I am New to Linux and computer booting so i don't know how to do***
Hi Friends i am new to Linux use androidx86 to test my android apps in my pc , i download iso file from official site and use Etcher to Create a bootable sd card inside my usb sd card reader and i use live cd to run. but i create it in a 16 GiB sd card. but etcher partition it into same size(+100mb extra free space) of iso , but now i want to install huge apps in it so what should i do to extend size.

***Thanks in advance and sorry for mistakes ***
 *Feel Free to Edit or Close this Question*

Comment: ISO image files have a _fixed_ (not \[easily\] changeable) image size based on the size of the ISO image. On the SD card, you will need to: Create an additional partition (or more, _and_ mount it/them) to use the additional space on the SD card; _**OR**_ You will have to go through the process of _resizing_ the partition _and_ file system, which can become problematic when using an ISO image; _**OR**_ Just _install_ the base OS directly to the SD card using the OS's installer tools--instead of simply  _copying_ the ISO image to the SD card.

Comment: @C.M. Thank you , Your Comment Resolved my problem .